# Box of text in php gd

Tags: php, gd

I want to make box of text having story in it...copy on image using GD library.i want it beacause i have to save image for further puporse.

Comment: I've heard that Google seems to know quite a bit about this subject...

Answer (score 0):

Start by looking into [imagettftext](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php) and what you'd need to get that working.  For example, [this site](http://blog.ninedays.org/2007/11/29/writing-text-to-images-with-php/).